# How to restrict some names to not be used or written in an html name input?

Tags: php, html, restriction

I have a name input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
```

How to block names like "admin" or other names from being written in the box before the submit is made but allow other names to be used.

Comment: use some Javascript to check the values before submission. You can find examples of this kind of thing if you search for "javascript validation" online. What have you researched or tried so far? N.B. If you truly want to enforce this restriction then you need to write the same validation rules in PHP as well, since any client-side restrictions can be disabled or bypassed by a moderately knowledgable user.

Comment: Use Js on change and compare value input to one in an array of not allowed values

Comment: I need someone to write that

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with the HTML5 attribute `pattern` (the validation will happen after you hit return, i. e. try to submit the form):

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="name"
 pattern="(?!^[aA][dD][mM][iI][nN]([iI][sS][tT][rR][aA][tT][oO][rR])?$)(?!^root$).{3,20}"></form>
```

Here anything is accepted that is between 3 and 20 characters long and is not "admin" or "administrator" (case-insensitive) or "root" (in lower case).

Answer (score 0):

This Snippet Demonstrates on client-side approach using JavaScript. For Security reasons check this again on server side.

```js
function validate()
{
var inputVal = document.getElementById("name").value;
invalidList=["admin","administrator"];
if(invalidList.indexOf(inputVal) !== -1){
        document.getElementById("val").innerHTML="Invalid";
    } else{
        document.getElementById("val").innerHTML=inputVal;
    }
}
function validateSubmit()
{
var inputVal = document.getElementById("name").value;
invalidList=["admin","administrator"];
if(invalidList.indexOf(inputVal) !== -1){
        alert("Invalid");
    } else{
        alert("Success");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" onkeyup="validate()"/>
<input type="button" onClick="validateSubmit()" value="Submit"/>
<div id="val"></div>
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt prevent the submit!
it just says "Invalid"
I want the box to not allow the name "admin" and replace it to empy and a message or pop up says this name is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use some form of JavaScript validation for this. Here's a dumbed-down answer in jQuery. You can add as many names as you'd like to an array then check to see if the name typed in is in the array. If you're submitting the form to a server, PHP validation would probably be the best option.

```js
$("#submitName").click(function() {
  var username = $("#name").val();
  if(username == ("admin" || "administrator")){
    $('.success-message').html("Name not allowed");
    //write code to preven form from submitting
  }else{
    $('.success-message').html("Submitted successfully");
    //write code to allow the form to submit
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
<button type="submit" id="submitName">Submit name</button>
<div class="success-message"></div>
```